# Multiple BeforeRightClick and normal right click

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook i am working on where one page has the need for multiple buttons.  However, i have chosen to use the `beforerightclick` on set cells instead as this fits the sheet and the users better.

I have several `beforerightclick` rules that work fine.  My issue is that the user can no longer right click anywhere else in that sheet.

I found an example on another website that does allow the right click to work, however, it doesnt allow multiple targets with their own rules. Unless i have missed something, which could be the case think this is week 3 in doing VBA.

Here is my code: -

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
       If Target.Address = "$A$13" Then
            If Range("B12") = "Yes" Then
            Call Item_1_Get_Data
            End If
            If Range("C12") = "Yes" Then
            Call Item_2_Get_Data
            End If
            If Range("D12") = "Yes" Then
            Call Item_3_Get_Data
            End If
            If Range("E12") = "Yes" Then
            Call Item_4_Get_Data
            End If
            If Range("F12") = "Yes" Then
            Call Item_5_Get_Data
            End If
       End If

        If Target.Address = "$B$13" Then
            Call Item_1_Get_Data
        End If

        If Target.Address = "$C$13" Then
            Call Item_2_Get_Data
        End If

        If Target.Address = "$D$13" Then
            Call Item_3_Get_Data
        End If

        If Target.Address = "$E$13" Then
            Call Item_4_Get_Data
        End If

        If Target.Address = "$F$13" Then
            Call Item_5_Get_Data
        End If

        If Target.Address = "$B$10" Then
            Call SimpleVersion
        End If

        If Target.Address = "$C$10" Then
            Call DetailedVersion
        End If
   Cancel = True
End Sub
```

This is what i have found, but i cant get this to work with all the different right click criteria i have set.  I am obviously missing something.  Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:B3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Cancel = True
'
'your code here
'
End Sub
```

If i used `intersect(target, Range(A13,B13,C13,D13,E13,F13,B10,C10))` i believe i can only have one rule on this right click.

If i do multiples of `intersect(target,Range(a13)` then say `intersect(target,Range(B13)` it works on the first but not the second or anymore.

Thank you,

Comment: Hi @SJR yeah, apologies that is just a copy and paste on from the website.  I was trying to say that if i use something like that with range, i dont know how to get it to do different things based on different ranges as `Range("A13,B13,C13 etc.` would apply on one rule. where as each cell has a different rule.  If i do multiples of that version as i have in my formula using that method it only works on the first rule and not the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove:

```
Cancel = True
```

this will allow normal right-click behavior for "normal" cells.

Comment: OMG! Thank you, what does this do out of interest?

Comment: @StevenByrne  `Cancel` dismisses the interrupt with no action taken.  So the usual behavior of displaying the Context Menu does not occur!

Comment: Hi @Gary's Student that appears to actual work but cause the right click option to still open after it has run what it needed to do.  However, as you taught me what it does, i added it back in before each `End IF` and that works perfect.  No pop up on the selected cells, but a pop up everywhere else.  Really appreciate the help!